# Is the statement still true?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a entire function. Suppose that there is $M$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left|f(z)\right|<M\left|z\right|^n$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\left|z\right|\geq 1$. It is well known that in this case $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$. Now if I suppose to have have it just for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, can I conclude the same?

I would say yes. We will just not get the if and only if. So if $f$ is a polynomial of degree n than we can not bound it like this.

Comment: Your condition is more restrictive, therefore the conclusion still holds.

Comment: If $|f(z)| \leq M|z|^n$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $|f(z)| \leq M|z|^n$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z| \geq 1$ in particular?

Comment: Yes, your condition is more restrictive, in the sense that, in principle, it could apply to a smaller amount of functions. That is, if $f$ is such that $(\forall z\in\Bbb C):|f(z)|<M|z|^n$, then, in particular, $|z|\geqslant1\implies|f(z)|<M|z|^n$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: As Mindlack mentioned, the condition "something happens for $|z|\ge 1$" is implied by the condition "something happens for all $z$". So the latter is a stronger condition, since it implies the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If your condition holds for all $C$ then it holds for the subset that you needed to apply the theorem and so the theorem still applies.

I suppose you need only worry about the fact that you might have made the condition overly restrictive so that no nonzero function will satisfy it. However you need not worry since take $K<M$

$$|Kz^{n}|=|K||z|^{n} = K |z|^{n} < M |z|^{n}$$

So $f(z)=Kz^{n}$ will satisfy your inequality.